# React Hook Form + MUI - How to display watched item into another textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

Using React hook Form V7, I'm trying to retrive a value from a component's Textfield and display the value on the fly, into a Textfield in another Component.
I've tried watching it, it works great outside of the Textfield, but as soon as I insert the value, I'm getting the : *"Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled"*...
I've tried everything I could think of and searched the internet all around but couldn't find anything helping... Is there a way to achieve this?

My code so far:

```
const watchCake = watch("cake");

 <Controller
    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref }, formState }) => (
         <TextField
            disabled
            id="cakeName"
            name="cakeName"
            margin="dense"
            variant="outlined"
            onChange={onChange}
            value={watch("cake")}
            ref={register}
            {...register("cakeName")}
         />
      )}
      control={control}
      name="cakeName"
      defaultValue=""
/>
 <p>{watchCake}</p> //works perfect
```

@knoefel

I've splitted my form and inputs into serveral components for reusability. The form is in a dialog, which will trigged the right components parts when needed.
So I'm having a "ChildOne" component with a Textfield. On the fly (not on validation) I need to display what the user types there, into another Textfield in the "ChlidTwo" component (this is only to avoid user's confusion when entering other data in ChildTwo)

Here's an image for better understanding :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `setValue` provided by RHF to update the value of the "cakeName" `TextField` after the value of your "cake" `TextField` has changed.

Also, if you are using `Controller`, there is no need for `register` as `Controller` takes care of registering your external component.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="cake"
  defaultValue={""}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <TextField
      label="Cake"
      value={value}
      onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
        setValue("cakeName", value);
        onChange(value);
      }}
    />
  )} 
/>
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="cakeName"
  defaultValue={""}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <TextField label="Cake Name" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form V7 - Material UI Set Value]

**UPDATE**

With the new requirements your initial approach using `watch` was correct. You have multiple options here to pass the current input value to your child component:

**Option 1**

Spread the form methods (the return value of the `useForm` hook) to your child components and use `watch` there.

[image: Edit React Hook Form V7 - Material UI Set Value -- watch]

**Option 2**

Just pass `control` as a prop to your child components and use the `useWatch` hook to receive the current value of the watched input. Doing it with `useWatch` behaves similarly to Option 1. However, this will isolate re-rendering at the component level and potentially result in better performance for your application. I would go this route if your child form components are very complex and have many inputs.

[image: Edit React Hook Form V7 - Material UI Set Value -- useWatch]

**Option 3**

Use [FormContext](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext/) - it solves the problem where data is passed through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level. This also causes the component tree to trigger a re-render when React Hook Form triggers a state update, so i would try to avoid it as this has the worst performance of all the options and is not necessary in your use case.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. It's great to have introduced me to setValue, thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I think my issue is that both inputs actually are children of the parent form (I didn't express myself clear enough I think - gonna edit my question) could this be the problem?

Comment: No worries, and thanks for the update. But unfortunately I still don't fully understand the use case. Can you possibly show more code, for example both components, so that it is more obvious what should happen?

Comment: Sure, thank you so much for helping :) Gonna edit my question

Comment: Ok, thx for the details. What isn't clear is - can all "child input" components  be rendered together, or just one at a time? So if the user modify the value of input 1 of "child inputs 1", will "child inputs 2" be visible?

Comment: Yes, they render together. I have a bundle exactly like the picture. The 3 Child components render & validate well. If the user type something in ChildOne, the value should reflect in ChildTwo. The user could also modify the 1st value, and then it would reflect again... until validation. In the end, the reflected value won't be stored anyway, it's just to help the user.

Comment: Ok. Isn’t that just a placeholder you want? If I understand you correctly: the user types “test” in input 1 of “child inputs 1”, then input 1 of “child inputs 2” has also the value “test”? But what I don’t get in your explanation: what if the user makes changes in the input 1 of “child inputs 2”, then change the value in “child inputs 1” again. Will then be the input value in “child inputs 2” overwritten? I hope my question is somehow understandable? :)

Comment: Yes I understand :) And yes, if the user makes a change in input1 of "ChildOne" the mirrored value in the ChildTwo's input will be overwritten. Also yes, what I need is like a placeholder.

Comment: I updated my answer and used the placeholder prop to show the current value of the other input unless the user types anything in the input field. Please let me know if this is your desired behaviour.